# Can an arbitrary-length parameter array be turned into nested loops?

Tags: c#, loops, syntax, nested

Is there anyway to achieve the following in C# (or any other ,Net language)?

```
public double nestedParamArrayLoop(function delegatedFunction, LoopControllers loopControllers)
{
    double total = 0;

    NestedLoopControllers loopControllers = new NestedLoopControllers(loopController, loopMaxes);

    foreach(LoopController loopController in loopControllers);
    {
        nestedfor (loopController)
        {
            // this line results in one or more loopControllers being passed in
            total += delegatedFunction(loopController);
        }
    }

    return total;
}

public double delegatedFunction(params int[] arguments)
{
    // dummy function to compute product of values
    long product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Count ; i++)
        product *= arguments[i];
    return product;
}
```

Where delegatedFunction is called with a variable number of parameters, according to the number of controllers in the array loopControllers?  Each loopController would contain a start value, a max value and an increment value (i.e. template a for loop).

The syntax above doesn't quite work as I'm not sure any exists to capture this paradigm.  But the idea is that you can specify an arbitrary number of nested loops and then the nesting is done for you by the compiler (or the runtime).  So it's a kind of templated nesting where you define the loop conditions for an arbitrary number of loops and the environment constructs the loops for you.

For example

- NestedParamsArrayLoop(delegatedFunction, loopContoller1); results in iterated calls to delegatedFunction(values for loopValue1);
- NestedParamsArrayLoop(delegatedFunction, loopContoller1, loopController2); results in
  iterated calls to delegatedFunction(values for loopValue1, values for loopValue2);
- NestedParamsArrayLoop(delegatedFunction, values for loopContoller1, values for values for loopController2, loopController3); results in
  iterated calls to delegatedFunction(loopValue1, values for loopValue2, values for loopValue3);

The goal of this is to avoid writing separate functions with different numbers of arguments but where the actual guts of the logic is common across them.

I hope I've done a decent job of explaining this but if not please ask!

Comment: I suppose you may achieve this by a recursive method.

Comment: The "syntax" in your question looks more like pseudo code then like c#...

Comment: Well yes it has to be pseudo-code, because I don't know how to write the real thing (if it's even possible).

Comment: So if I pass 3 "controllers" that will result in 3 nested for loops (say with loop variables i,j,k), and inside all those loops is call to `delegateFunction(i,j,k)`?

Comment: Seems like an XY-problem. You think the solution of your problem is Y, thus you want to solve that, instead of asking what the actual solution for your original problem X was. So what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Evk, yes, exactly.  So if I pass in one LoopController then you get delegateFunction(i).  If I pass in two LoopControllers then you get delegateFunction(i,j).  And with three as you say, delegateFunction(i,j,k).  With four (i,j,k,l).  etc.   Sorry if I haven't explained this perfectly but I find it hard to express.  And yes the code is pseudocode (and even has an error in it).

Comment: HimBromBeere The exact algorithm I trying to solve is a generic approach to 2D, 3D, 4D interpolation.  The interpolation works exactly the same way per dimension and results in wasteful/risky duplication of code.   I'm not sure I understand how a recursive function would work when the number of parameters is variable.

Comment: All - thanks for very quick responses.  It will be great to solve this.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I can see here why you say it seems like an XY-problem.   There is indeed a specific issue I'm working on (interpolation in any number of dimensions) but the question of variable-depth nesting of loops has come up in other areas too, hence I posed it as a theoretical/syntactic question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is pretty much what you want to do.

Start with a `LoopController` definition:

```
public class LoopController : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public int Start;
    public int End;
    public int Increment;

    private IEnumerable<int> Enumerate()
    {
        var i = this.Start;
        while (i <= this.End)
        {
            yield return i;
            i += this.Increment;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Enumerate().GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can define `NestedParamArrayLoop` like so:

```
public double NestedParamArrayLoop(Func<int[], double> delegatedFunction, List<LoopController> loopControllers)
{
    double total = 0;

    foreach (LoopController loopController in loopControllers)
    {
        total += delegatedFunction(loopController.ToArray());
    }

    return total;
}
```

Now the rest is easy:

```
void Main()
{
    var loopControllers = new List<LoopController>()
    {
        new LoopController() { Start = 4, End = 10, Increment = 2 },
        new LoopController() { Start = 17, End = 19, Increment = 1 },
    };
    Console.WriteLine(NestedParamArrayLoop(DelegatedFunction, loopControllers));
}

public double DelegatedFunction(params int[] arguments)
{
    long product = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Count(); i++)
        product *= arguments[i];
    return product;
}
```

You could even define `NestedParamArrayLoop` as this:

```
public double NestedParamArrayLoop(Func<int[], double> delegatedFunction, List<LoopController> loopControllers)
{
    return
        loopControllers
            .Select(lc => delegatedFunction(lc.ToArray()))
            .Sum();
}
```

---

Is this more like what you're after?

```
public double NestedParamArrayLoop(Func<int[], double> delegatedFunction, List<LoopController> loopControllers)
{
    Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> getAllSubsets = null;
    getAllSubsets = xs =>
        (xs == null || !xs.Any())
            ? Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>()
            : xs.Skip(1).Any()
                ? getAllSubsets(xs.Skip(1))
                    .SelectMany(ys => new[] { ys, xs.Take(1).Concat(ys) })
                : new[] { Enumerable.Empty<int>(), xs.Take(1) };

    double total = 0;


    foreach (LoopController loopController in loopControllers)
    {
        foreach (var subset in getAllSubsets(loopController))
        {
            total += delegatedFunction(subset.ToArray());
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: Wow let me try that....  oh man that's really clever.  I had an idea that a yield might be involved.... thanks!!   Will get back to you later today...

Comment: Nice. I was starting to write something similar but you where faster. One thing to note is that your implementation requires Start to be less than Stop - otherwise you get an infinite loop in your Enumerate() function.

Comment: @BitRacketeer I thought you need another thing. There are no nested loops here

Comment: @Evk - The OP needed to expand the parameters to pass to the delegated function - I think that's what he meant by a nested loop.

Comment: @Evk & Enigmativity - I want to iterate each parameter in the arbitrary-length parameter array.  So with one parameter 1, 2, 3, 4.  With two parameters (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), then (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4).  Then (3,1)...(3,4).  And with three params (1,1,1), (1,1,2),(1,1,3),(...); then (2,1,1).(2,1,2),(2,1,3)(...) etc.  I find it hard to explain in words - "arbitrary-depth nesting or a parameter array" is the closest I can get so far.

Comment: @Enigmativity maybe a better way of describing what I am after is "dynamic nesting".  That's succinct and a bit closer.

Comment: Just found this which looks interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536833/arbitrary-number-of-nested-loops

Comment: @BitRacketeer - I see what you're after now. Would it be right to say that you want every possible selection of the input values? From the `null` set to the full set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, including every permutation?

Comment: @BitRacketeer - I've added a further option to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP asked for a solution in any .NET language, I wrote one in F# (translating @Enigmativity's answer). No NestedLoopController class required:

```
[[ 4 .. 2 .. 10 ]; [ 17 .. 1 .. 19 ]]
|> Seq.map (fun args ->
    (1L, args)
    ||> Seq.fold (fun a x -> a * int64 x))
|> Seq.sum
|> printfn "%d"
```

You can probably translate this to C# LINQ in a relatively straightforward way…

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really need is what is called cartesian product of multiple sets. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) is good article from Eric Lippert about doing that with arbitrary number of sets in C#. So create function like this (I won't explain it because I cannot do this better than Eric did in his article):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) {
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
    foreach (var source in sources) {
        var tmp = source;
        result = result.SelectMany(
            seq => tmp,
            (seq, item) => seq.Concat(new[] { item }));
    }               
    return result;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
foreach (var n in CartesianProduct(Enumerable.Range(1, 4), Enumerable.Range(1, 4))) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", n));
    // in your case: delegatedFunction(n);
}
```

outputs

```
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
1, 4
2, 1
2, 2
2, 3
2, 4
3, 1
3, 2
3, 3
3, 4
4, 1
4, 2
4, 3
4, 4
```

It's easy to replace `Enumerable.Range` with your `LoopController`, `Enumerable.Range` is used just as an example.